# Method for finding roots of real trigonmetric polynomial

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials, numerical-methods

Given a real valued trigonometric polynomial,

$$ f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k \cos(k x + \phi_k) $$

what is the current fastest numerical method to find the roots of the polynomial for a given error? I have just come across the Durand-Kerner method, are there any others?

Comment: I added the numerical-methods tag; it's the most important one here. Also, there is [scicomp.SE](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) site, and it really needs more questions to graduate...

Comment: Thanks, shall I repost it there or perhaps get a mod to move it?

Comment: Up to you, of course... you did get an answer here after I bumped and retagged the question. You can always request migration by flagging your question.

Comment: Have put a new question over at scicomp, with some changes. Thanks for the bump!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For finding the roots of an algebraic polynomial, I swear by the Jenkins-Traub algorithm, which I've found in practice to be both faster and more robust than alternatives. The only downside is that Jenkins-Traub is rather complicated if you must implement it yourself. Codes are available online, for instance I've used this C++ implementation: http://www.crbond.com/download/misc/rpoly.cpp

I would therefore use the standard substitution $y=e^{ix}$ to turn the trigonometric polynomial into an algebraic polynomial of degree $2n$, and then apply Jenkins-Traub.

Comment: Thanks, that was just the start I needed. I didn't realise there had been so much work done on this.